# If $p(z)\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ and $c>0$ why does $A_c:=\{z\in\mathbb{C} \ | \ |p(z)|=c\}$ consist of a finite number of closed paths?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Let $\displaystyle p(z)=\sum_{i=0}^na_iz^i\in\mathbb{C}[z]$ be a complex polynomial of degree $n$. For any $c>0$ prove the following fact:

> The set $A_c:=\{z\in\mathbb{C} \ | \ |p(z)|=c\}$ is the union of a finite number of closed paths.

**My idea:**

We know from the fundamental theorem of algebra that such a polynomial has exactly $n$ roots counted with multiplicity. So my understanding of the problem is that the number of (bounded) component of $A_c$ is equal to the number of distinct roots of $p(z)$ and that the boundary of each component is a closed path around the corresponding root (this closed curve wraps around the root as many times as its multiplicity). I tried to start with some examples:

If $p(z)=z$ is very clear since $A_c$ is the boundary of the ball centered in $0$ with radius $c$

If $p(z)=z+z^2$ I have some difficulties to understand what is going on.

It seems to me that at one point it is necessary to use the maximum principle for holomorphic functions.

**Bonus question:**

> Is it still true the above fact if we replace $p(z)$ with $p(z)e^{-f(z)}$, where $f(z)$ is an entire non-constant function?

Comment: The number of closed paths depends on the number of critical points inside; if $c$ is large enough so all critical points are inside there is only one jordan curve and the polynomial acts like a blaschke product inside it

Comment: @Conrad Could you please give a detailed proof or references in which I can found it? Thanks.

Comment: T Sheill-Small Complex Polynomials is the best reference for this; https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/complex-polynomials/66C9D6BF3190DA5B7C11D727E656B249